# How to hide Rails Admin CSV options while exporting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export, rails-admin

I have a Ruby on Rails app and am using I'm using [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin). I want to hide the export options such as **Encode to**, **No header** and **Column separator**. Is this possible?

I've tried this but surely it's wrong:

```
config.actions do
  dashboard                    
  end    
  index                        
  new 
  export do
    options ['encode']
  end
  # show_in_app
  ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
  # history_index
  # history_show
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate [to rails admin github page](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) and download the views folder. Copy this file **/rails_admin/main/export.html.haml** in the same directory of your project.If you don't have the directory create one.
Then comment these lines :

```
  / %fieldset
  /   %legend
  /     %i.icon-chevron-down
  /     = t('admin.export.options_for', name: 'csv')
  /   .form-group.control-group
  /     - guessed_encoding = @abstract_model.encoding
  /     %label.col-sm-2.control-label{for: "csv_options_encoding_to"}= t('admin.export.csv.encoding_to')
  /     .col-sm-10.controls
  /       -# from http://books.google.com/support/partner/bin/answer.py?answer=30990 :
  /       = select_tag 'csv_options[encoding_to]', options_for_select(Encoding.name_list.sort), include_blank: true, placeholder: t('admin.misc.search'), :'data-enumeration' => true
  /       %p.help-block= t('admin.export.csv.encoding_to_help', name: guessed_encoding)

  /   .form-group.control-group
  /     %label.col-sm-2.control-label{for: "csv_options_skip_header"}= t('admin.export.csv.skip_header')
  /     .col-sm-10.controls
  /       .checkbox
  /         %label{style: 'display: block;' }
  /           = check_box_tag 'csv_options[skip_header]', 'true'
  /       %p.help-block= t('admin.export.csv.skip_header_help')

  /   .form-group.control-group
  /     %label.col-sm-2.control-label{for: "csv_options_generator_col_sep"}= t('admin.export.csv.col_sep')
  /     .col-sm-10.controls
  /       = select_tag 'csv_options[generator][col_sep]', options_for_select({ '' => t('admin.export.csv.default_col_sep'), "<comma> ','" => ',', "<semicolon> ';'" => ';', '<tabs>' => "'\t'" }), placeholder: t('admin.misc.search'), :'data-enumeration' => true
  /       %p.help-block= t('admin.export.csv.col_sep_help', value: t('admin.export.csv.default_col_sep'))
```

Now The export options will be removed!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no configuration to do this.
You'll have to override the export view. You'll find it on the gems folder.
Copy it to your project, you'll find it this way:

```
cd $(bundle show rails_admin)
cat ./app/views/rails_admin/main/export.html.haml
```

The destination should be your projects root path and then the same path

```
./app/views/rails_admin/main/export.html.haml
```

You'll find the options you want to hide there in the form of an array that, for the encoding, looks like this:

```
Encoding.name_list.sort
```

And at the bottom of that file, you'll see the csv, json, xml options. Edit away to your hearts content.